# Live location and placing clickable markers on Openlayers

Tags: javascript, geolocation, popup, google-maps-markers, openlayers

I am brand new to using Openlayers and coding in general

I have, through much frustration, created a map on Openlayers, but it needs a bit more functionality.

I would like to add in the Geolocation of the user on the map. I have tried to insert the code from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html and w3schools. The toggle button appears and works but it will not show me the live location. I am probably missing something from the code but can't work out what.

Additionally, I would like to add markers to my map that, when clicked on, would show an image of the location in a popup bubble and the name. Again, I have tried multiple sites and re-wrote different codes but alas, nothing has worked, Not sure if I am overcomplicating it or not.

Can someone show me a code that would work for these functions? Or at least a website that can explain them me. As I say I am brand new so simplicity is key.

I should mention it's all been created using JavaScript and HTML if that helps.

Thanks!

Used code from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html and w3school for geolocation but the actual location did not show on the map.

Same with popup bubbles and markers

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Please do not just refer us to multiple external resources, from which you took parts of code to cobble your thing together - show us a proper [mre] of _your_ specific issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can't use the Geolocation API without HTTPS, except if you set some flags